# Eclipse not finding classes in main from test in imported maven project

Tags: eclipse, maven, jakarta-ee

I have an JavaEE EJB2 session bean project imported into Eclipse via its poms. This means the project is setup with multiple sources folders; for src/main/java, several target/generated-soures, and of course src/test/java.

The problem is that the classes in src/test/java uses TO classes in src/main/java. Eclipse keeps complaining about "AddressTO cannot be resolved to a type" in AddressTOTest.java. But the class is right there in src/main/java, I can open it, it has no compilation errors.

AddressTOTest has the same package as AddressTO, so it has no import statement for AddresssTO. But src/test/java initially is setup to compile to target/test-classes. However, changing this to target/classes does not solve the problem.

Comment: Have you pressed `Alt` + `F5` after that?

Comment: No, but Eclipse did detect the change and rebuild. Refreshing the Maven project is useless, because nothing was changed Mavenwise. But I tried it just now and it does not make a difference.

Comment: Could you please share the screenshot of the package structure in eclipse?

Comment: Sure: https://www.dropbox.com/s/r946beyb81usml9/Screenshot%20from%202015-03-13%2008%3A48%3A26.png?dl=0

Comment: What you see in the screenshot are many maven modules automatically loaded into Eclipse, a lot still have problems which I'm trying to solve. The one I'm looking into right now is the module that is unfolded. The src/main/java compiles without problems, it has AddressTO.java, but the src/test/java does find it.

Comment: FYI: I also have this project setup in IntelliJ and it finds in all the packages only one problem (a cyclic reference we need to get out).

Answer (score 0):

You need to add the import statement. Because, they may have the same package declaration, but they exist in different source folders. Class to be tested is in `src/main/java` and the test classes are in `src/main/test`

It would have worked without the import statement if the test class and the class to be tested are in the same source folder.

Comment: I already tried that of course. "The import com.nedap.aeos.io.domain.carrier.address.AddressTO cannot be resolved"

Comment: But I do not agree that it should have worked; there are in total five soures folders, each their classes directories is part of the compilation path, so they should find each other's classes no matter where the class files are.